# Who are "The Fallen" (Ha-Nofelim, הַנֹּֽפְלִ֑ים) God supports in Psalm 145:14?

Tags: psalms, hebrew-bible, fall

In Psalm 145:14, we are told God supports all The-Fallen.

Tehillim / Psalms 145:14 [MT]

> YHVH supports for-all The-Fallen ( סוֹמֵ֣ךְ יְ֖הֹוָה לְכָל־הַנֹּֽפְלִ֑ים )

**Who are "The Fallen" (Ha-Nofelim, הַנֹּֽפְלִ֑ים) God supports in Psalm 145:14?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psalm 146:8 shows some insight into Psalm 145:14.

> and gives sight to the blind. He lifts those who have fallen; he loves his **righteous** people.

Primarily, God is concerned with the righteous and those who are too weak to help themselves. The Lord loves those who look to him and support them with strength.

Comment: _Behold, his soul which is lifted up is not upright in him: but the just shall live by his faith._ Habakkuk 2:4 expresses where the strength of the upright comes from : the weak (and the fallen) become strong, in faith. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 1):

"The Lord upholds all who are falling, and raises up all who are bowed down"

These verses likely refer to God’s preferential concern for the weak, the poor and the lowly. The fallen are they whom God promises to help. The imagery is of God lifting and raising those who are in need or those who have fallen. Variations of this refrain can be found throughout the text:

“But you are the God of the lowly, helper of the oppressed, upholder of the weak, protector of the forsaken, savior of those without hope” (Judith 9:11)

“He raises up the poor from the dust; he lifts the needy from the ash heap” (1 Samuel 2:8)

“But he raises up the needy out of distress, and makes their families like flocks” (Psalm 107:41)

“He has brought down the powerful from their thrones, and lifted up the lowly” (Luke 1:52)